# tool for google adsense account analysis (app)

Tags: google-adsense, analytics, web-applications, software

does any one know of a tool to analyse my google adsense traffic / clicks ...

preferably a desktop solution...

Something which provides more advanced and easy analysis reporting solutions then adsense

thanks

Answer (score 1):

mmm. I don't know about a desktop solution, but you should try to integrate your adsense account with Google Analytics, so you can create your own dashboard with a lot of cool stuff and stats, and they will be updating/improving over the time.

I made a empty screenshot, it would be cool to show with data, but this is just for demostration purposes.

[image]

P.D. Sorry for my english, it's not my native lang